# Call environment variable in InfoPlist.strings

Tags: ios, xcode

I have this purpose string in my Info.plist

```
<string>$(APP_NAME) requires access to your photo library for you to attach a document image or selfie photo to your profile.</string>
```

I have localized to Indonesian, have created file InfoPlist.strings

```
NSCameraUsageDescription = "$(APP_NAME) memerlukan akses kamera agar Anda dapat mengambil gambar dokumen dan foto selfie untuk proses verifikasi.";
```

When I run the app, the permission pops up, it does not translate the variable `$(APP_NAME)`

How can I call the variable in InfoPlist.strings?